# Shortcut for switching to previous and next window in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, application-switcher, activities-overview

There doesn’t seem to be a solid way to do this. What I want to achieve is shortcuts to go to the previous window and next window.

When I said previous window, the one that displays before the current in the actovities window the next one being the one after.

I’m guessing these are ordered in time opened or time last used, but there doesn’t seem to be a shortcut for it, is it possible to make one?

I eventually want to use these shortcuts for swipe gestures to mimic the behaviour of Mac gestures

The alt tab shortcut doesn’t really do much. The Activities window shows based on window size/monitor while the tab menu shows the windows ordered by the stack. Neither really would work too easily for what I’m talking about for more than two tabs being cycled back and forth. Maybe I'm missing a config option or something but it appears as if you couldn't do it without making some kind of plugin.

Comment: just a shortcut to go back/forth in historic (creation) order through windows?

Comment: unless you have mucked about and changed defaults a simple  ...  alt-tab works then to go in reverse do ... shift-alt-tab ... as a side note mouse middle roller bar tap on top window boarder to lower that window - slick trick not found on osx etc.

Comment: Not sure why alt+tab is working for you but it just cycles back and forth for me and doesn’t actually go to the end.

Comment: Not sure why on getting down voted... the shortcuts clearly don’t exist for this specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to switch between differents windows then you have to use
  :

`Alt+Tab`: Switch between running applications

- If you want to switch between differents workspaces, then use:

`Ctrl+Alt+arrow`: Move between workspaces

In case none works, I would suggest you to get a look at your default keyboard shortcuts, you may see and change them in **Settings->Devices->Keyboard**.

Comment: As said in the comment section, this cycles, it doesn’t behave how you describe it.

Comment: Well it looks a bit harsh to downvote, I was just trying to help.

Comment: I wasn’t the one who downvoted.

Comment: I did not blame you personally, I just gave my opinion